# How to toggle a div visibility using radio buttons in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

```js
$(':radio').change(function(event) {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $('#' + id).addClass('none').siblings().removeClass('none');
});
```

```css
.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' data-id="bank" />
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' data-id="school" />
<hr />
<div id="bank" class="none">Bank</div>
<div id="school" class="none">School</div>
```

I want to show and hide div using radio buttons but this code doesn't work for me I got this code here in stack. It seems fine in jfiddle but when I used it it doesn't work.

Comment: Put your JS code in DOM ready like `$(function() { //your existing code });` and it will work fine.

Comment: thanks bro appreciate it can I give you a hug xD I mean a check

Answer (score 0):

Put your jquery code inside document.ready like this:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(':radio').change(function (event) {
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            $('#' + id).addClass('none').siblings().removeClass('none');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your script tag at the bottom of `<body>` tag or use [defer](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Document Ready](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ready/) method.

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(':radio').change(function (event) {
     var id = $(this).data('id');
     $('#' + id).addClass('none').siblings().removeClass('none');
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: If it worked, I explain why

```css
.none {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' data-id="bank" />
  <input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' data-id="school" />
  <hr />
  <div id="bank" class="none">Bank</div>
  <div id="school" class="none">School</div>
        
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(':radio').change(function (event) {
      var id = $(this).data('id');
      $('#' + id).addClass('none').siblings().removeClass('none');
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio').click(function (event) {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $('#' + id).addClass('none').siblings().removeClass('none');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.none {
display:none;
}
</style>
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' data-id="bank" />
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' data-id="school" />
<hr />
<div id="bank" class="none">Bank</div>
<div id="school" class="none">School</div>
```